# "Could not find a part of the path" error message

Tags: c#, file-io

I am programming in c# and want to copy a folder with subfolders from a flash disk to startup.

Here is my code:

```
private void copyBat()
{
    try
    {
        string source_dir = "E:\\Debug\\VipBat";
        string destination_dir = "C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destination_dir))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destination_dir);
        }       

        // Create subdirectory structure in destination    
        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(source_dir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destination_dir + dir.Substring(source_dir.Length));          
        }

        foreach (string file_name in Directory.GetFiles(source_dir, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(file_name, destination_dir + file_name.Substring(source_dir.Length), true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "HATA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

I got an error:

> Could not find a part of the path E:\Debug\VipBat

Comment: You are using verbatim string literals `@""` in which case you don't need to escape out `\\` - just use a single slash.

Comment: @StuartLC is right. If you use _verbatim string literal_, your string will be exactly as what you write. In this case, it will be exactly E:\\Debug\\VipBat\\ which is not a valid path.

Comment: Shouldn't you fill `{0}` present in `E:\\Debug\\VipBat\\{0}`? Another thing you don't need two slashes in the path when you prefix the string with `@`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: I didn't use @ and I am sure the path is right, but I got the same error. the code is updated...

Comment: @user3313131: Why you have edited the question after getting the right answer?
Now, Questing above doesn't match the answers below. which will confuse the new users.

Answer (score 25):

The path you are trying to access is not present.

```
string source_dir = "E:\\Debug\\VipBat\\{0}";
```

I'm sure that this is not the correct path. `Debug` folder directly in `E:` drive looks wrong to me. I guess there must be the project name folder directory present.

Second thing; what is `{0}` in your string. I am sure that it is an argument placeholder because folder name cannot contains `{0}` such name. So you need to use `String.Format()` to replace the actual value.

```
string source_dir = String.Format("E:\\Debug\\VipBat\\{0}",variableName);
```

But first check the path existence that you are trying to access.

Comment: use Path.combine()

Comment: The error is not self-explanatory. A non-existent path is not 'a part of the path'

Comment: @tno2007 It could not find the part that does not exist!

Answer (score 10):

There's something wrong. You have written:

```
string source_dir = @"E:\\Debug\\VipBat\\{0}";
```

and the error was

> Could not find a part of the path E\Debug\VCCSBat

This is not the same directory.

In your code there's a problem, you have to use:

```
string source_dir = @"E:\Debug\VipBat"; // remove {0} and the \\ if using @
```

or

```
string source_dir = "E:\\Debug\\VipBat"; // remove {0} and the @ if using \\
```

Answer (score 4):

Is the drive E a mapped drive? Then, it can be created by another account other than the user account. This may be the cause of the error.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with privileges? It's funny that I opened visual studio as an administrator and the code stopped working complaining "Could not find a part of the path". This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If the user who's accessing this path is an Active Directory user , then this error might be generated.

Answer (score 4):

We just had this error message occur because the full path was greater than 260 characters -- the Windows limit for a path and file name. The error message is misleading in this case, but shortening the path solved it for us, if that's an option.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, although in my case the problem was with the formatting of the DESTINATION path. The comments above are correct with respect to debugging the path string formatting, but there seems to be a bug in the File.Copy exception reporting where it still throws back the SOURCE path instead of the DESTINATION path. So don't forget to look here as well.

-TC

Answer (score 2):

```
File.Copy(file_name, destination_dir + file_name.Substring(source_dir.Length), true);
```

This line has the error because what the code expected is the `directory name  + file name`, not the file name.

This is the correct one

```
File.Copy(source_dir + file_name, destination_dir + file_name.Substring(source_dir.Length), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably unrelated, but consider using `Path.Combine` instead of `destination_dir + dir.Substring(...)`. From the look of it, your .Substring() will leave a backlash at the beginning, but the helper classes like Path are there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

There can be one of the two cause for this error:

1. Path is not correct -  but it is less likely as CreateDirectory should create any path unless path itself is not valid, read invalid characters
2. Account through which your application is running don't have rights to create directory at path location, like if you are trying to create directory on shared drive with not enough privileges etc

Comment: In my case, the Security settings on a network folder I did not own did not give sufficient permissions to the service user could so it could access the file. Would have been really nice if the error message included _why_ the access failed instead of making us guess. The exception doesn't even have an inner exception to assist debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue by simply restarting Visual Studio with admin rights.

The problem was because it couldn't open one project related to Sharepoint without elevated access.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be the issue: **Space in the folder name**

Example:
Let this be your path:
string source_dir = @"E:\Debug\VipBat";

If you try accessing this location without trying to check if directory exists, and just in case the directory had a space at the end, like :
**"VipBat    "**, instead of just **"VipBat"** the space at the end will not be visible when you see in the file explorer.

So make sure you got the correct folder name and dont add spaces to folder names. And a best practice is to check if folder exists before you keep the file there.