# How to get files from directory symlink

Tags: c#, file

i try to get list of paths from directory symlink. It's write exception

> Could not find a part of the path.

```
var filePath = @"C:\symlink";

var paths = new List<string>((Directory
  .GetFiles(filePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
  .OrderBy(x => new FileInfo(x).Name));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796687/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-error-message

Comment: Check if directory exists: `if (Directory.Exists(filePath)) {...}`

Comment: It's enter to: if (Directory.Exists(filePath))

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if directory *exists*; e.g. if we want to get an *empty list* when the directory is abscent:

```
var filePath = @"C:\symlink";

var paths = Directory.Exists(filePath)
  ? Directory
      .EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .OrderBy(file => Path.GetFileName(file))
      .ToList()
  : new List<string>();
```

Please, note that we don't have to use `GetFiles(...)` which reads *all* the files into an *array* but can just enumerate the files with `EnumerateFiles`

Comment: The directory contains batch of sub folders and files. The directory symlink is target from network driver.

Comment: @Kosta Sidorenko: if you want to scan all subdirectories then `SearchOption.AllDirectories` is the right option; please, check, if `symlink` is a *correct map* of network drive, i.e. if system can address it as a *directory*.