# Could not find part of the path

Tags: c#

I've created a billing app that creates a pdf. My issue is the pdf doesn't get created because the header for the pdf isn't being fond, i get a "could not find part of the path c#".
I've tried changing the location of the folder and also including it in the bin folder.

```
var imagepath = @System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .Location + @"\..\..resources\pdfHeader.png";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var png = Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), ImageFormat.Png);
    png.ScalePercent(25f);
    png.SetAbsolutePosition(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width - 559f - 2f , pdfDoc.PageSize.Height - 2f - 115f);
    pdfDoc.Add(png);
}
```

Comment: You've got `\..resources` in your path. Is that a typo or the problem?

Comment: @gunr2171 - it is the tyblem, a typo that grew into a problem :)

Comment: Note that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns the path of the executable, including the executable file name. Plus, you cannot use the Project's `Resources` folder in your application, that folder is used by Visual Studio to store a copy of embedded resources: it won't exist when you deploy. Use the Image as an Embedded object or add the object to a Folder you created in the Project's structure and configure it to `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer`. `Output Directory` will be `\Bin\Debug` or `\Bin\Release`, depending on the active configuration profile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Could not find a part of the path" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796687/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-error-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, a part of the path is missing (ie. one of the folders in the path doesn't exist). This is most likely caused by this:

```
 \..\..resources\
```

You forgot a `\` before `resources`. :)

By the way - please follow naming conventions ([here's an official link for C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)) for all languages you code in. Your variable should be called `imagePath`.

Hope I could help!

Comment: thank you so much, it was actually the "..." before resources that has was the problem